# grep result or variable not being redirected into file as expected

Tags: bash, shell

I`m trying to make my first bash-script. Here is the problem:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_INP=./BASIS_DURAND
ARRAY=($SCRIPT_INP/*/)
i=0
file_name=${1}
touch "${file_name}"
echo "${SCRIPT_INP}" > "${file_name}"
a="${#ARRAY[@]}"
echo $a
while (( "$i" < "$a" ))
do
    echo "${ARRAY[i]}" 1>> $file_name
    cd "${ARRAY[i]}"ELAST/
    const=$(grep -A 6 'ELASTIC TENSOR CONSTANTS' *.cryst.out) 1>> "$file_name"
    echo "$const" 1>> "$file_name"
    (( i++ ))
    cd ${SCRIPT_INP}
done
```

The script writes all directories into file (echo "${ARRAY[i]}" 1>> $file_name), but second "echo" in this loop doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: `while (( i < a ))` is just as valid and easier to read. Math contexts don't need quoting or explicit expansion operators.

Comment: also, `1>>` is redundant. `>>` does the exact same thing.

Comment: Also, you can just put `exec >>"$file_name"` at the top of your script, and that redirects all future stdout much more efficiently than re-opening the file every time you're going to run a command that writes to stdout.

Comment: Also, don't use all-upper-case names for variables which are neither special or exported to the environment if you want to avoid name collisions.

Comment: Also, quote your expansions. `echo "$a"`, not `echo $a`; `array=( "$script_inp"/*/ )` rather than `array=($script_inp/*/)`. Otherwise you get surprising behavior when there are spaces, newlines, glob characters, etc. in your values.

Comment: @kojiro Can't really fit it all in one comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
const=$(grep -A 6 'ELASTIC TENSOR CONSTANTS' *.cryst.out) 1>> "$file_name"
echo "$const" 1>> "$file_name"
```

is a strange pair of expressions. The first one captures standard output (fd 1) to a name, and then redirects it to a file. But it was already captured, so it won't be redirected.

The second would append the expansion of `$const` to the file, and probably works, but the *first* expression is not actually writing anything to the file.

Comment: Yes, first "1>> "$file_name"" should be deleted. But second line does not work anyway

Comment: Found my mistake.
echo "$const" 1>> "$file_name" was creating file in subdirectory. But I was waiting for this file in starting directory.
I`ll be more attentive next time